# Odoo: Adding data which is coming from a api in the tree view by click of a button

Tags: python, api, synchronization, odoo

I have added a Sync button on the top of tree view header which is supoosed to populate data coming from the api in the tree view

[image]

This sync button triggers a python function in models.py  which is getting data from the api . I want to populate that data in this tree view when i click the Sync button? I am not able to figure it out how to do this?

Comment: In your model, if you are getting a data in form of json object you can use something like
data_json = json.loads(json_data)
and then map your fields:
for id in data_json.keys:
    result = {}
    result.update({'ID':id})
    final_list.append(result)
and similarly for other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sync method in python at the server should be able to create new records and write/update existing ones. In your JS sync button you just need to reload the tree view dataset of records to show the new information or do something when a response to the sync call is received. Something like triggering tree view `reload` or `reload_content` depending on your version